# Document Library - sort by (HELP)

Tags: document-library

I have a large Document Library and set up a Category as such:

2.1 Recruitment 
2.2 Equal Rights
2.3 ... etc. 
2.10 Data Protection

I have set the Group By: Category but the issue / trouble is:
***the 2.10 is being displayed right after the 2.1***

[image]

Any advise on how to overcome this issue?

Also tried to Group By: ID but not much luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how string sorting works in SharePoint. If you want it to sort normally, you'll need to update all the section values to be like 2.01, 2.02, etc and it'll be sequential at that point.

Comment: right :( I guess there is no other way around! I just went and updated the Category numbers, but realised that now all the files (that are assigned to their categories) are not being updated.  Meaning having to edit each file and re-select the renamed category. Is there a quicker way ?!

Comment: Unfortunately not, but you could use Datasheet view (that's what it's called in 2010 at least, not sure about 2013+) and more quickly change each one.

Comment: Use data sheet view, you can sort it by the Section field, update 1 item, then drag the value down like in Excel to bulk update the rest of the fields. Otherwise use PowerShell or script to update them.

Comment: Ahhhh I got it now :) cheers guys